# Magento Admin Header above phtml Content?

Tags: magento-1, adminhtml, header

Currently in the Admin Panel my custom phtml page is under the header:
[image]

**app/code/local/Sean/MasterCreate/Block/Adminhtml/Warehouse/Display.php**

```
<?php

class Sean_MasterCreate_Block_Adminhtml_Warehouse_Display extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'product_id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'mastercreate';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_warehouse';
        $this->_mode = 'display';

        $this->setTemplate('finance/action.phtml');

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        return Mage::helper('mastercreate')->__('MYJ Finance / Inventory');
    }

    //This is automatically tied to where the form action goes/is
    public function getSaveUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/warehouse/updateInventory');
    }
}
```

The getHeaderText() function puts the header text under my phtml page created through the following:
**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/finance.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_warehouse_createwarehouseform>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="adminhtml/template" name="warehouse_display" template="finance/action.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_warehouse_createwarehouseform>
</layout>
```

**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/finance/action.phtml**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>MYJ Finance Page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<script src=""></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app/code/local/Sean/MasterCreate/controllers/Adminhtml/WarehouseController.php**

```
<?php

class Sean_MasterCreate_Adminhtml_WarehouseController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function createWarehouseFormAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
        $this->_addContent(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mastercreate/adminhtml_warehouse_display')
        );
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('adminhtml/session'); //this will allow flash messages
    }
}
```

Where do I specify what comes first?  I can edit to display additional files if necessary just let me know!

Answer (score 0):

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml
```

there you have nothing usefull. You ccan add something before echo $this->getGridHeader()

or you can try to do something with notices, but it isnt best idea:

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addNotice($this->__('your text'));
```

Comment: Well i'm going to put a lot of stuff on the phtml page. But I want it all to be under the header.  How can I get the action.phtml to be under the header text

Comment: I don't want to write in the grid.phtml because then It'll apply to all future files I create